# Best way to detect if request came from a different domain or a sub domain

Tags: php

I'm building an application that uses sub domains and custom domain names that sit in the database for users, so if a request comes from another domain I'll check from the database if that custom url is indeed there or when the request comes from a subdomain, I'll check if that's there. If it is I do my stuff.

Consider this a simple example of I'm looking for:

```
if(is_user_request())
{
    $url = get_url();
    // assuming that get_url() magically decides whether to output ..
    // a custom domain (http://domain.tld)
    // or a subdomain's first part (eg. "this".domain.tld)
}
else
{
    // otherwise it's not a sub domain nor a custom domain,
    // so we're dealing with our own main site.
}
```

Now before you go ahead assuming that because I have 0 rep, I'm here asking for "teh codes". I have a completely working way of doing this, which is the following:

```
// hosts
$hosts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

// if there is a subdomain and that's under our $sitename
if(!empty($hosts[1]) AND $hosts[1] === Config::get('domain_mid_name'))
{
    $url = $hosts[0];
    $url_custom = false;
}

 // if there is no subdomain, but the domain is our $sitename
 elseif(!empty($hosts[0]) AND $hosts[0] === Config::get('domain_mid_name') AND !empty($hosts[1]) AND $hosts[1] !== Config::get('domain_mid_name'))
    {
    $url = false;
    $url_custom = false;
}

// otherwise it's most likely that the request
// came from a entirely different domain name.
// which means it's probably $custom_site
else
{
    $url = false;
    $url_custom = implode('.', $hosts);
}

if($url)
{
    return $url;
}

if($url_custom)
{
    return $url_custom;
}
```

However, I'm sure there are better way of doing this. Because first of all, HTTP_HOST does not include 'http://', so I need to add that manually and I'm pretty sure this entire if, else thing is just an overkill. So, people smarter than me, enlighten me, please.

Oh and, no .. I do not have pre-defined sub-domains. I have a simple wildcard *.domain.tld set up, so all sub-domains go to the main script. I'm just saying this because from my search for a solution I found numerous answers that suggested to manually create a sub-domain, which is not even remotely related to what I'm asking, so let's skip that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is the way to go.

But there are errors in your code. You're assuming that host names sent consist of 2 or 3 components but you can't be sure of that. You should at least check `count($hosts)` too.

If by example you use domain.tld for your own site then you're better off with first checking if `domain.tld` is sent (you return your page, fast); then see if `substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']...,-11)==='.domain.tld'` and if so, return the subsite (works with any level of subdomain, still fast); else error-recovery, since a completely foreign domain has been routed to you. The key thing to note is that domain matching from the hierarchy's top means matching the hostname strings right-aligned:

```
        .domain.tld | subsite-pattern
   sub12.domain.tld | MATCH
   sub12.dumain.tld | NO MATCH
    sub12domain.tld | NO MATCH
```

Comment: This is a way better answer. And note on the speed is much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is the correct way to do it unless you want to pass different parameters from your web server into PHP.

As for the protocol, be aware the request protocol should be determined by `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` rather than assuming it's `http`.

For extracting the subdomain you could look at using [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) and then running

```
$subdomain = array_shift(explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
```

But generally what you have is how it should be done.